# Adding an ascending timer to a program

Tags: c

I am making a simple game with c , I need to add a time counter showing time passed after the user types s (to start the game), I need it to be updated every second without affecting the other printed items, and I have no idea how could it count the time regardless what the user is doing in the game!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`time()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time).

Call it once as the game starts, and remember the value:

```
const time_t time_start = time(NULL);
```

Then in your main loop (I assume you have one), compute the elapsed time:

```
const time_t elapsed = time(NULL) - time_start;
```

This value is the time in seconds since the game started, and you can format that into a string and display that as needed.

Comment: I already made that but at that case I only can update the time when the player make an action so I could calculate and print the new time

but what I need is if the player was idle for a minute it should be updated automaticly.